# Cut, copy and paste from long press menu look like Material buttons

Tags: android, material-design

I've been experimenting with the new Material library so far, and noticed that the long press menu for TextInputEditText shows cut, copy, paste and other options as material buttons within the menu. I haven't done any custom code and the long press menu is system default. What's happening?

[image]

I've implemented 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3' and all libraries are androidx. Testing on SDK23.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="io.jayasurya.ruby.MainViewModel"/>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".AddFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:text="@={viewmodel.name}"
            android:id="@+id/nameInput" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="@{viewmodel.name}" />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Styles

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Looks like you've applied styling to default button classes.  Specify your own style and then reference that style on your Okay button.  Add your style/theme and layout code for a chance at a better answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [ask] for some tips to improve your question.

Comment: @CodeChimp Do long press menu items count as buttons which can be effected by app, too?

Comment: It would appear that the material lib does get affected by your colorAccent.  Try using a standard EditText and see if that exhibits the same behaviour.  Could be a bug/feature.

Comment: I have a part of my app which has the exact same dependency and uses TextInputEditText but it does not exhibit this behavior. The only difference is that I extended Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar, so perhaps this is just a bug with the DarkActionBar theme?

Comment: No, happens with a normal EditText and, @Nick Moven, happens irrespective of what the theme is, unfortunately.

Comment: **UPDATE** This happens in my old device which runs on Marshmallow 6.0, and I ran it on an emulator with android P, it works just fine, the usual long press menu. So is it a bug in the Material library for older devices? Thanks people, for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by material design view inflater, and [Google has fixed it](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/3ec2906ad866521673c9a98df45bfa14682bbc33).